# codeblocks segmentation fault

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am learning how to debug using c++ codeblocks. but everytime i run dubug
I get a call stack window and a segmentation fault. It doesnt matter what the program is, the error is always exactly the same message even if it runs ok. I have read up on it and viewed many other similar faults, and tried some of there solutions, but i have not solved the problem. I have a image of the windows and like i said the words never change, even in the call stack.
[image: Error Messeges]

Comment: did you read http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks? Especially "Make sure that the project is compiled with the -g (debugging symbols) compiler option on, and the -s (strip symbols) option off. This ensures that the executable has debug symbols included. "

Comment: I have been through this and ticked -g, I cannot seem to find -s(strip symbols option though? Sorry found it and it is off.